# Как правильно обособить оборот с "несмотря на"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь еще запятые и если да, то сколько?

Хочу пожелать, чтобы даже несмотря на самые грандиозные проекты и далеко идущие планы развития оставалось время на общение с любимыми людьми, ведь, в конечном счете, это самое главное!

Answer (score 1):

Хочу пожелать, чтобы, даже несмотря на самые грандиозные проекты и далеко идущие планы развития, оставалось время на общение с любимыми людьми, ведь в конечном счете  это самое главное!

1) Частица ДАЖЕ включается в состав оборота.

2) Наречие "в конечном счете" рекомендуется не обособлять.

Answer (score 1):

***Хочу пожелать, чтобы, даже несмотря на самые грандиозные проекты и далеко идущие планы развития, оставалось время на общение с любимыми людьми, ведь, в конечном счете, это самое главное!***

***Обороты со словами несмотря на, невзирая на обособляются.***
Например:  *Несмотря на непогоду, мы двинулись в путь; На собрании критиковали, невзирая на лица; Сонного, как ветка, утонувшая в пруду сна, несла Нэй на руках великолепно спящего сына, раскидавшего, несмотря на малую величину свою, богатырские ноги и руки (Цв.); Несмотря на запрет врачей, я написал в Малеевке повесть «Колхиду» (Пауст.)*
***Оборот со словами несмотря на не обособляется только в случае тесной смысловой связи с глаголом, причем в постпозиции.***[Обособленные обстоятельства](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/265-obosoblennyeobstoyatelstva.html)